# Split string so that all + datain to one list and - data in to another

Tags: c#

I am having my string as follows where I would like to separate in such a way it should give me all `+` data in to one list and `-` in to other list.

```
string InputStr = "DIM H + QUT OF PIP DIM - DIM L + XYZ - ABC";
```

My expected will be as follows

```
string[] Positives = "DIM H QUT OF PIP DIM XYZ"
string[] Negatives = "DIM L ABC"
```

And when I match it with original string I would like know whether it is `+` or `-` when a match found.

```
public bool FindMatchesInStringArray(string markup, string[] strArray, out string matchString)
{
    bool flag = false;
    matchString = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Match Match = Regex.Match(markup, strArray[i].Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (Match.Success)
        {
            flag = true;
            matchString = Match.Value;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Here in `markup` I will send `DIM H` or some other so that when a match found it should give me `+ DIM H` or `-ABC`.

Comment: Okay, now we know what you want. And where is the question? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service for free, by the way. Read the [ask] topics first before asking a question.

Comment: Will it always alternate between positives and negatives? or will their sometimes be multiple of the same sign in a row?

Comment: Question I have explained what I am doing and what is expected

Comment: I have a non regex solution using lists. Will it suffice?

Comment: always positives and negatvies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Non Regex solution:

```
static List<string> ListOfPositive = new List<string>();
static List<string> ListOfNegative = new List<string>();
static bool InitialPositiveCheck = false;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string InputStr = "DIM H + QUT OF PIP DIM - DIM L + XYZ - ABC";
    AddToLIst(InputStr);
    ListOfPositive.Reverse();
    ListOfNegative.Reverse();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", ListOfPositive));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", ListOfNegative));         
}

static void AddToLIst(string newstring)
{
    if (!(newstring.Trim().StartsWith("+")) && !InitialPositiveCheck)
    {
       newstring = "+ " + newstring;
       InitialPositiveCheck = true;
    }

    int indexOfPlus = newstring.LastIndexOf("+");
    int indexOfMinus = newstring.LastIndexOf("-");

    string str = "";
    if (indexOfMinus == -1 && indexOfPlus == -1)
        return;

    if (indexOfPlus < indexOfMinus)
    {
       str = newstring.Substring(indexOfMinus + 1);
       ListOfNegative.Add(str);
       str = newstring.Remove(indexOfMinus);
       AddToLIst(str);
    }
    else
    {
       str = newstring.Substring(indexOfPlus + 1);
       ListOfPositive.Add(str);
       str = newstring.Remove(indexOfPlus);
       AddToLIst(str);
    }
 }
```

Link to [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/suIfCK)

Output:

```
 DIM H  QUT OF PIP DIM  XYZ 
 DIM L  ABC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MySpliter
{
    public List<string> PositiveSplit(string text)
    {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();

        string[] splitedText = text.Split(' ');
        bool positive = true;

        foreach (string t in splitedText)
        {
            if (t.Equals("+"))
            {
                positive = true;
            }
            else if (t.Equals("-"))
            {
                positive = false;
            }
            else if (positive)
            {
                temp.Add(t);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public List<string> NegativeSplit(string text)
    {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();

        string[] splitedText = text.Split(' ');
        bool negative = false;

        foreach (string t in splitedText)
        {
            if (t.Equals("+"))
            {
                negative = false;
            }
            else if (t.Equals("-"))
            {
                negative = true;
            }

            else if (t.Equals("-"))
            {
                negative = true;
            }
            else if (negative)
            {
                temp.Add(t);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MySpliter ms = new MySpliter();
        string InputStr = "DIM H + QUT OF PIP DIM - DIM L + XYZ - ABC";
        List<string> positive = ms.PositiveSplit(InputStr);
        List<string> negative = ms.NegativeSplit(InputStr);


        Console.WriteLine("Positive");
        positive.ForEach(text => Console.Write(text + " "));
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Negative");
        negative.ForEach(text => Console.Write(text + " "));
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do negative function in the same way

Comment: You can do them both in one pass. Have a list of positives and a list of negatives. If positive=false, add to negative list instead of positive list.

Comment: i always use SRP (better for reuse, foe example if from one place you want only the positive)

Comment: Your choice. I'm more flexible with SRP-I think that it depends how specific the function is.

Answer (score 1):

One method I would try is to create two stringbuilders and then loop over the char[] one index at a time, check if any control sign (+ or -), set a local state to point to one of the stringbuilders and then pipe the following chars into this stringbuilder...

Something like this:

```
var sb, sb1, sb2;

for (c in string)
{
  if (c == '+') sb = sb1;
  else if (c == '-') sb = sb2;
  else sb.Append(c);
}
```

Comment: switching the identifier is clever. I like it!